# Python Won't Run "this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"

Tags: python-2.7

When i try to run python.exe or IDLE or any compiled exe i get this error:

**"this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"**

I reinstalled many times and still won't work.

Comment: Looks like missing DLLs to me.

Comment: how do i know if its missing any DLLs

Comment: What is your system? How did you install it?

Comment: I'm usng XP SP3, it used to work fine days ago, then i uninstalled it because i used to install alot of frameworks (or libraries), and now it won't work

Comment: Solved: All i had to do was installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistrubitable.